# List is putting everything in one row instead of multiple rows in Excel? (Pandas/Python)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have an Excel with a list of Zip Codes. The Zip Codes are fed into a ISP Search engine that shows the best internet providers by you. I take the top three using Selenium and append them to 3 different lists. I am trying to then output those Top 3 internet providers into three columns, which it does, but everything is in one row instead of multiple rows under each column.

This is
the current result:

[image: Current Result]

And this is the expected result (also don't want the \n printing out as well as the brackets):

[image]

This is the function:

```
#Function to loop through all last names starting with A through Z

def CheckXfinityList():

#Reads the excel file
df = pd.read_excel("BranchAddressList.xlsx")

#Specifies the column we want info from and assigns it to a variable
address = df["Zip Code"]

#Create values for lists for Providers to put into their columns
pv1 = []
pv2 = []
pv3 = []


for x in address:

    try:
        #srchbtn = SeleniumSetup.driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="main-content"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/button/img')
        #if srchbtn exist
        #srchbtn.click()
        SeleniumSetup("https://www.highspeedinternet.com/providers")
        # Find the "Zip code" box and enters text into it from the excel document
        link = SeleniumSetup.driver.find_element("id",'providerHero')
        link.send_keys(x)

        # Hits the "Enter" key to search the zip code
        link.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(5)

        #Grab top provider names
        provider1 = SeleniumSetup.driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="residential"]/div[3]/div/div[1]')
        provider2 = SeleniumSetup.driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="residential"]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]')
        provider3 = SeleniumSetup.driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="residential"]/div[5]/div/div[1]')


        pv1.append(provider1.text)
        pv2.append(provider2.text)
        pv3.append(provider3.text)
    except:
       print("Couldn't find the value")

    finally:
        SeleniumSetup.driver.quit()

# Creates new Excel file that will list Top 3 Internet providers in there area
top3 = pd.DataFrame({'Zip Code': [address],
                     'Internet Provider 1': [pv1],
                     'Internet Provider 2': [pv2],
                     'Internet Provider 3': [pv3]})


#Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('TopProviders.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

#Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
top3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

#Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

I've seen methods on here so just .explode the list but that hasn't worked for me and I think the issue is just how I am appending them to the list, perhaps I need another loop for them? Any help is appreciated! (Also my function is not showing as indented properly on this site so don't worry about that)

Comment: did you check the results of top3 variable?

Comment: instead of writing : 'Internet Provider 1': [pv1], 'Internet Provider 2': [pv2], 'Internet Provider 3': [pv3], can you try by writing : Internet Provider 1': pv1, 'Internet Provider 2': pv2, 'Internet Provider 3': pv3..
The one you have written is making a list of lists, Hence everything came in a single row.

Comment: @Yagami_Light Perfect! That is the solution

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**. You've posted way too much code and the issue has nothing to do with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

@Yagami-Light had the correct solution. Removing the brackets around the variables in the Dataframe solved the issue. It was making a list of a list